# Is it possible to get types from an unknown array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I am getting Icon names from an imported library and mapping through them like this:

```
import * as Icons from "@icons";

// an array of icon names ["ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight" ect]
const IconNames = [...Object.keys(Icons).map((icon) => icon)] as const; 
// for sizes prop
const IconSizes = ["sm", "md", "lg"] as const;
```

But when I try to get types from the array it just comes up as string:

```
icon: typeof IconNames[number]; //this is type string
size: typeof IconSizes[number]; //this is type "sm" | "md" | "lg"
};
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it not possible to get the type for `icon` from an unknown array `"ArrowLeft" | "ArrowRight"`?

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: const IconNames: Array<keyof Icons> = [...]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeh this is a gap in TypeScript: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208.

Your only choice is to cast it to `keyof Icons`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This worked.

`const keys = Object.keys as <T>(o: T) => Extract<keyof T, string>[];`

`const IconNames = keys(Icons);`

Question is, is it ok to do this?

Comment: Yeh its safe in your case as the argument to not do it does not apply to you. Icons is static and can be evaluated at build time.